# Save longitude and latitude in SQLite database

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, sqlite, mapkit

I am creating a map application in Objective-C, for iPhone. I know how to get the current location of the user, and the destination location. As a user travels, his coordinates (latitude and longitude) change.

How can I save the latitude and longitude of the user in an SQLite database every five minutes as the user travels?

Comment: @Ciryon: you should make this an answer.  It's better than using NSTimer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timer and set time interval to 300, as shown below

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 target:self selector:@selector(*savetodatabase*) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Make one function which is called every 5 mins and save it to database.

**NOTE:** Here 300 is in seconds

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you really always want to store the coordinates every 5 minutes. When using Core Location you subscribe to events that the user has changed position (and you can set accuracy) so you can get notified when the user has moved at all, and then choose to store the coordinates in a database. If you don't get events, then you know the user hasn't changed position.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method by using NSTimer which will add lat and long do database.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:<(NSTimeInterval)ti> target:<(id)aTarget> selector:<(SEL)aSelector> userInfo:<(id)userInfo> repeats:<(BOOL)yesOrNo>]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use timer that after every 5 min  a call to SAVEDATABASEFILE method